# How to generate and handle errors in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, networking, error-handling

I'm working on an app where users need to login. The webapplication uses a token, that users can get from calling a webservice using their username and password. My question now is what's the best way the handle errors that can occur. What I have now:

LoginViewController.swift

```
self.api.token(forUsername: "a", password: "b") { (result) in
    switch (result) {
    case .failure(let error):
        print("something when wrong \(error)")
    case .success(let token):
        print("token \(token)")
}
```

LoginAPIClient (the self.api) using https://github.com/3lvis/Networking

```
class LoginAPIClient {

enum ResponseError: Error {
    case unexpectedDataError
    case unknownError
}

enum Result {
    case success(String)
    case failure(Error)
}

lazy var networking: Networking = {
    let networking = Networking(baseURL: APIClient.serverURL())
    return networking
}()

func token(forUsername username: String, password: String, completion: @escaping (Result) -> Void) {
    let parameters = ["username" : username, "password" : password]
    networking.post("/api/login", parameters: parameters) { (result) in
        switch result {
        case .failure(let response):
            return completion(.failure(response.error))
        case .success(let response):
            if var token = response.headers["Authorization"] as? String {
                token = token.replacingOccurrences(of: "Bearer ", with: "")
                return completion(.success(token))
            }
            return completion(.failure(ResponseError.unknownError))
        }
    }
}
```

}

Here for example I'm creating my own error `return completion(.failure(ResponseError.unknownError))` in case the server responds with a successful status code (200) but somehow the Authorization header is missing from the response.

This works, the only problem is that now when I handle the error in the ViewController I don't know the exact reason why it fails. For example, from the Networking library I get an error code (400 or 401 etc) but this is lost because first it was an NSError. I could use an NSError but somehow this doesn't feel right. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

One of the solutions I thought of was to add an extra enum and then do something like this:

```
enum Result {
    case success(String)
    case networkFailure(FailureJSONResponse)
    case failure(Error)
}

self.api.token(forUsername: "a", password: "b") { (result) in
switch (result) {
case .failure(let error):
    print("something when wrong \(error)")
case .networkFailure(let response):
    print("something when wrong \(error)")
case .success(let token):
    print("token \(token)")
```

}

But I rather have just 1 success and 1 failure in the switch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every application usually has its own "Error", so in your case you can define

```
public enum AppError: Swift.Error, CustomStringConvertible {
    case networkError(code: Int)
    case anotherError(message: String?)
    case underlying(Swift.Error)

    public var description: String {
        switch self {
            case .networkError(let code):
                return "Network error with code \(code)"
            default://I'm not gonna cover all cases, but you should :)
                return "Error"
        }
    }
}
```

then you can use your approach

```
enum Result {
    case success(String)
    case failure(AppError)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a clean way to implement the error handling!

Answer (score 1):

You can add second parameter to `completion` block:

`func token(forUsername username: String, password: String, completion: @escaping (Result, error: ResponseError?) -> Void)`